# Set imageview bitmap in callback listener

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-imageview

So I have a CameraFragment which is called from MainFragment.The problem is I am using a custom Listener to pass the image Data to MainFragment.java.Here is how I call the CameraFragment.java

In MainFragment.java:

```
public static class MainFragment extends Fragment implements CameraFragment.CameraFragmentHolder.CameraListener {

    ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mImageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        return rootView;
    }
    private OnClickListener onCameraFragmentClicked = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, CameraFragment.CameraFragmentHolder.newInstance(MainFragmentHolder.this, 0, false));
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    };



    @Override
    public void onImageSaved(byte[] data) {
        if (data != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Didn't get any result");
    }
    }
}
```

Then in CameraFragment.java I implement the following:

CameraFragment.java

```
private byte[] mCameraData;
private CameraListener mListener;

public interface CameraListener {
    public void onImageSaved(byte[] data);
}

private OnClickListener mDoneButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mCameraData != null) {
            removeCameraView();
            sendImageDataToListener();

        } else {
            mCamera = null;
            removeCameraView();
        }
    }
};

//Send image back to Listener
private void sendImageDataToListener() {
    if (mCameraData != null) {
        mListener.onImageSaved(mCameraData);
    } else {
        Log.v("CAMERA IMAGE ERROR:", "NO IMAGE DATA");
    }
}

private void removeCameraView() {
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

My problem is in MainFragment in the CallBackListener when I try to setImageBitmap nothing happens.

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: you can't do this ... with basic android knowadge(like fragment's lifecycle) it should be obvious that mainfragment has no view when is on backstack ...

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan My problem is in MainFragment in the CallBackListener when I try to setImageBitmap nothing happens.

Comment: @Selvin so how do I go about implementing something similar to this idea?

Comment: 1. save data in camerafragment 2. pass the uri for saved data to the parent activity .. 3 when mainfragment will back from the backstack(in onCreateView) ask parent activity for uri and load the bitmap ... or any other solution which can be found with simple googling

Comment: @Selvin could you write a few lines? and removed the on backstack from the code and still doesn't work. Don't think the on backstack is the problem

Comment: @Selvin could you please post a solution to this?

Comment: @Selvin Could you take a look at my Solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So @Selvin it 's actually possible. What I did was onViewStateRestored. I read over the android API a bit. This shouldn't give any problems but I 'm still skeptical about it since I' ve not fully tested it.i modified the MainFragment.java as follows.

In the MainFragment.java:

```
    Bitmap cameraImage;

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);

    if (cameraImage != null) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(cameraImage);
    }
}

@Override
public void onImageSaved(byte[] data) {
    if (data != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        cameraImage = bitmap;
    }
} else {
    Log.v(TAG, "Didn't get any result");
}
```